# Bigquery Regex for special characters

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

Below is the sample code that has a long string partitioned with special character "»". I need to pull the string which are before the first and third special character(»).

```
    with test as (
    select 'AA»BB»CC»DD»EE»FF' string union all
    select 'ZZ»XX»RR»PP»EE»FF' )

    SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(string, r"([^»]*)") AS string_1 from test
```

Using the regex which is in code i could extract the first part of the string which is "AA" and "ZZ". But is there is any way to extract the letter before the third special character "»", where the expected output should be "CC" and "RR"

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SPLIT` instead of a regex:

```
with test as (
  select 'AA»BB»CC»DD»EE»FF' string union all
  select 'ZZ»XX»RR»PP»EE»FF'
)
SELECT SPLIT(string, '»')[OFFSET(2)] AS string_1 from test
```

This returns `"CC"` and `"RR"` as output.

Comment: Thanks much @Elliott brossard

Answer (score 1):

as alternative

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH test AS (
  SELECT 'AA»BB»CC»DD»EE»FF' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ZZ»XX»RR»PP»EE»FF' 
)
SELECT code
FROM test, UNNEST(SPLIT(str, '»')) code WITH OFFSET pos
WHERE pos = 2
```

with result as

```sql
Row code     
1   CC   
2   RR
```